# script spawn via atd leaves a process stuck in wait

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, at

I have a `bash` script which is run via `at`, I run it like
`echo "bash /path/to/my/script.sh" | at -M now` because I want it
to run detached.

When the script is spawned, immediately I see 2 instances (`ps`), and
even after my script completes successfully, another instance just
wont terminate. It will get reparented to pid `1` and just keeps doing
wait ( `strace` shows `wait4(-1...`).

I am not able to figure out why or how this second instance is forked!
When I run the script without `at`, I don't see the second process.
Any hints/tips to debug this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >/tmp/$$.log
exec 2>/tmp/$$-2.log

set -x

echo "1"
echo "2" >&2
```

This will redirect the whole output of the scripts stdout & stderr to the specified log files (in this case, `/tmp/<pid>.log` and `/tmp/<pid>-2.log`) and the stderr part of the logfile will contain each command it executes. You can use this output to follow the execution of the script and see, where it hangs...

content of 17958-2.log :

```
+ echo 1
+ echo 2
2
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already added a tracing logic with `exec 4 > log.trace; BASH_XTRACEFD=4 ; set -x` but the child process logs are not seen here or are getting overlapped! I will try to use the `pid` in log name.